# Facebook JS SDK: "(#100) No permission to publish the video" error

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I'm trying to publish a video file to my Facebook feed

My App is in **Development** mode

Here is how I init an SDK:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    initFacebook();
});

function initFacebook(){
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
     appId      : '2xxxxxxxx7',
     cookie     : true,
     xfbml      : true,
     version    : 'v3.1'
    });

    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
}
```

Here is how I login:

```
var FB_ACCESS_TOKEN = null;
var FB_USER_ID = null;

FB.login(function(response) {
   if (response.status === 'connected') {
     FB_ACCESS_TOKEN = response.authResponse.accessToken;
     FB_USER_ID = response.authResponse.userID;
   } 
}, {scope: 'publish_video'});
```

Then I have a file input and its event callback:

```
<input id="video-picker" type="file"/>

$("#video-picker").change(function (event) {
   var file = this.files[0];
   post(file);
});
```

And now I'm trying to post:

```
function post(file){
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('title', "My awesome video title");
  formData.append('description', 'My awesome video');
  formData.append('source', file);
  var url = 'https://graph-video.facebook.com/v3.1/' + FB_USER_ID + '/videos?access_token='+FB_ACCESS_TOKEN;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data){
      console.log("SUCCESS", data);
    },
    error: function(data) {
      console.log("ERROR", data);
    }
  });
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#100) No permission to publish the video",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 100,
      "fbtrace_id": "D16rmDQzzT6"
   }
}
```

I do not understand what is wrong:

- I added the 'publish_video' permissions
- I/m trying to upload a '.mov' file

Here is the permissions my token has:

```
{
  "data": [
  {
    "permission": "publish_video",
    "status": "granted"
  },
  {
    "permission": "public_profile",
    "status": "granted"
  }
  ]
}
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: It seems like Facebook hasn't re-enabled this in API yet...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will answer my own question:

I asked the same question at Facebook Developers group https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/permalink/1966752140034957/

And one guy gave me an explanation:

1. no way to post to a user's timeline via API (probably this happened after 1st of August, 2018)
2. this only works via API if post to a page using page token
3. the only possible way to share a video from Web is to use the Sharing Dialog https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog/

it's not what I wanted to do, but at least it's clear now